# google map only loads half of its portion,i have used some extra javascript for some effects on the map but its only loading half

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have tried to use some hide/show functionality to my google map where a certain portion of the map is showed initially and after clicking on a button the whole map shows up.everything is working fine but when i click on the button and try to see the whole map,only half of the map shows up and the other half is covered with some gray color.here is the code

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <style> 

          #thediv {
        height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize() {

                                    var locations = [

                                      ['Nepcreation,sydney branch', -33.867487, 151.20699, 3],
                                      ['Nepcreation,kaulalampur branch', 3.140345, 101.689206, 2],
                                      ['Nepcreation,kathmandu', 27.689390, 85.335494, 1]
                                    ];

                                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('thediv'), {
                                      zoom: 2,
                                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.689390, 85.335494),
                                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    });

                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                    var marker, i;

                                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                                        map: map
                                      });

                                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                        return function() {
                                          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                        }
                                      })(marker, i));
                                    }
                                    }
                                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

        <div id="thediv" class="reveal-closed"></div>   
                                  <input type="submit" onClick="gmap()">

        <script>
    function gmap(){

        var x=document.getElementById("thediv");

        if(x.style.height=="100px"){
        x.style.height="600px";}
        else{
            x.style.height="100px";
        }


    }
    </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your code works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa25B/) (where it is loaded in the head and run by the window onload event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem faced by many users(including myself).

First you have initialized the Google maps within given dimension`(auto x 100px)`, based on it the map images(called as tiles) are loaded into it.

Then based on the `button` 's **`click`** you're changing it dimension `(auto x 600px)` therefore the **excess part of Google images are not rendered** but showing only the grey area.  In order to fix it what you have to do is to trigger the `resize` event as mentioned below

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

---

In your code, the map variable is scoped within the `initialize()` whereas the `click` event of button calls `gmap()`.  So lets keep the `map` variable as **`global`** and then follow the below code:

```
function gmap() {
    var x = document.getElementById("thediv");
    if (x.style.height == "100px") {
        x.style.height = "600px";
    } else {
        x.style.height = "100px";
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
}
```

<sub><sub>PS: In order to give a detailed explanation to this new user I have added this as my answer instead of marking it as duplicate.</sub></sub>

Comment: i may sound silly but i couldnt figure out how to make that map variable global.

Comment: @ashish declaring outside the function and at the top most script tag.. http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/xHT3k/

Comment: i did made the map global variable and used google.maps.event.trigger(map,"resize") but it isnt working yet!

Comment: Those are jolly small px amounts for an 8K screen.